# How to take or check the value from Dynamic Generated HTML CheckBox on Aspx.vb Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

I am using Html Check Box that is generated dynamically on the page.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='chk_"+kDyn+"' name='chk_"+kDyn+"' value='"+0+"' checked />
```

When I tried to get the value from checkbox it always returns 0 even if, it is checked or not checked

on Code Behind I am trying it as

```
ChkInsStatus=Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form("chk_" & intCounter))
IF  ChkInsStatus = 0 Then                   
    Response.Write("  got  ")
else
    Response.Write("  not  ")
End If
```

it always prints got.. even if I checked the check box or unchecked it.. how to do it
I am using aspx vb

Comment: I'm not familiar with vb.net, but can't you put a `runat="server"` attribute on the element and grab the checkbox through the id?

Comment: u are right but i am using dynamic checkbox which are looped using javascript that do not take runat="server" it says put the control in form tag

Answer (score 0):

That's because the value is not an Int32 and always returns default 0.
If the checkbox were checked then it returns the value else returns null.So you can get it's value like this:

```
chkValue = Request.Form("chk_" & intCounter)
IF  chkValue <> NULL Then                   
   Response.Write("The value is:" & ChkInsStatus)
Else
   Response.Write("The value is not selected.")
```